# Using the app.config file to connect to a SAP company object

Tags: c#, sdk, sapb1

I recently learned how to use `app.config` to save connection strings for my `.net` projects. Which I found very helpful if I ever change something in the connection string and the project has already been released.

Now, I'm working with the `company` object from SAP's B1 SDK, and I don't want to keep the connection details in hardcode. Since it's not just a connection string(as far as my knowledge goes) so I was wondering if `app.config` can also store my connection details for the `company` object.

This is how I usually make connections with the `company` object:

```
        oCompany = new SAPbobsCOM.Company();

        oCompany.Server = "servername";
        oCompany.language = SAPbobsCOM.BoSuppLangs.ln_Spanish_La;
        oCompany.DbServerType = BoDataServerTypes.dst_MSSQL2008;
        oCompany.LicenseServer = "localhost:30000";
        oCompany.UseTrusted = false;
        oCompany.DbUserName = "dbusername";
        oCompany.DbPassword = "dbpassword";
        oCompany.CompanyDB = "companyDB";
        oCompany.UserName = "cusername";
        oCompany.Password = "cpassword";

        lRetCode = oCompany.Connect();
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925638/add-values-to-app-config-and-retrieve-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karol's comment is on-point, here's how we usually setup ours. Only additional comment is that depending on what your deployment environment looks like, you might want to encrypt the sensitive credentials in your app.config (passwords).

```
// In code
Company company = new Company
{
    Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevServer"],
    DbUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevDBUser"],
    DbPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevDBPassword"],
    CompanyDB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevDatabase"],
    UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevSBOUser"],
    Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevSBOPassword"],
    language = BoSuppLangs.ln_English
};

// In your app.config
<appSettings>
   <add key="DevServer" value="DEV-SAP-SRV"/>
   <add key="DevDBUser" value="sa"/>
   <add key="DevDBPassword" value="sapassword"/>
   <add key="DevSBOUser" value="manager"/>
   <add key="DevSBOPassword" value="1234"/>
   <add key="DevDatabase" value="SBO_COMPANY_NAME"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Hi, should I have the encrypted password already in my `app.config` and just have a decryption method in my code?