# Change value in the config file c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have config file.I need to update this file manually from the code .My code is almost works but problem is with special characters like "<" or ">".
When I run the code I can see inside of the file this row and not html code.
How to avoid convention of characters "&", "<"?

The result of this code is: [image]

```
        string path = @"C:\path\filename.exe.config";
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(path);

        XmlNodeList textlist = xml.GetElementsByTagName("setting");
        string depName = string.Empty;
        string siteName = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < textlist.Count; i++)
        {
            if (textlist[i].OuterXml.Contains("DepartmentName"))
            {
                string xml1 = "<value> Test</value>";
                textlist[i].InnerText = xml1;
            }

        }
        xml.Save(path);
```

[image]

Comment: do you need to escape the unusual characters? this is done with the \ character

Comment: I need to have         <value>test</value>

Comment: You don't need to and actually *can't* save application setting changes to an application's `exe.config` file. It's write-protected just like any other file in `Program Files` for good reason. Saving user settings is *easy*, just call `.Save` on the Settings class

Comment: @Leo if you want users to change that setting it shouldn't be an *application* setting. You can create a `User` setting in the `Settings` tab that users can actually modify and save. Check [Application and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)

Comment: I am not running this file from project.I need to modify it outside from different app.

Comment: @Leo that doesn't change the fact that it's the *application settings* and therefore *shouldn't* be changed after installation. What are you trying to do? Store user settings? Apply a transformation? Why are you trying to encode strings by hand? XML serialization takes care of encoding automatically

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9445812/6560478; you can load the conf and edit it

Comment: Besides, *yes*, when you store a *string* inside XML it *will* be encoded. There's absolutely nothing wrong with those screenshots. That's what a string is supposed to look.

Comment: I have old app.Before uninstall I need to take department name.After install new version I need update department  name.The first part done.I have only problem with special character

Comment: @Leo all apps work the same. There's nothing wrong with that screenshot, that's how XML appears when you *serialize it as string*. When you load it again it will be OK.

Comment: Thanks.I will try

Comment: @DragandDrop the reason files in `Program Files` are read-only is to prevent bad edits by users or malicious programs. A bad entry in app.config will *prevent* the program from working because .NET will throw when trying to load the config. In this case it's unexpected XML content inside a `serializeAs="string"` setting

Comment: @DragandDrop besides, there *are* valid ways to make changes during deployment or after installation. Use user settings. Apply an xdt transformation during deployment. NuGet and Chocolatey apply `xdt` transformations during installation. Or an action in the setup package can use setup parameters to modify the file during the setup process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [InnerXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx) property (instead of InnerText)

E.g. code will be like this:

```
textlist[i].InnerXml = xml1;
```

Comment: Very very very bad idea. That's the *app.config* file with the setting marked as `serializeAs='string'`. I'm not 100% sure what this will do but it may *prevent* the application from starting at all, or it may result in an exception when trying to load the obviously invalid string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I absolutely agree with you. Right solution: use ConfigurationManager for configuration patching (possible - define custom ConfigurationSection). However, the question was: "how can I inject XML?", so the answer was "use this property". This solution is absolutely correct for small in-house applications, because it is simple.